# Will new GCP Kubeflow Pipelines deployment support Containerd?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, containerd, google-container-os

The default node image for version 1.18.17-gke.100 will be changed to Container-optimized OS with Containerd.  From what I know this doesn't work with Kubeflow Pipelines 1.4.1, specifically with the underlying argo implementation.  This is the typical error you will run into:

```
Failed to wait for container id '60b93fa7392926e132e8a3c3c336d55d1ba85734a85cd519a786c2be86b4334a': 
Error response from daemon: No such container: 60b93fa7392926e132e8a3c3c336d55d1ba85734a85cd519a786c2be86b4334a
```

Will the pipeline deployment get an updated to support Containerd?

Answer (score 0):

The support for docker-less execution will come after the upgrade to Argo 3 which is currently pending.
We've tried the PNS executor of Argo 2, but found it to be flaky.